# C - Returning 2 values in a function and trying to use them

Tags: c

So I have this function where I return 2 values:

```
return result, result2;
```

Now what I am trying to do is use these 2 values in my main function. I want to save it into a variable in main function like this :

```
variable = function(a,b);
```

But how do you specify here which value you want?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you cannot do this in C, you can just return one value. The comma operator returns just the last value, so you are actually returning the second one.

You can pass data by reference, like

```
function(&a, &b);

void function(int *a, int* b){
    *a = 42;
    *b = 666;
}
```

You can also put them in a structure and return it or even a pointer to a *dynamically* allocated structure.

```
typedef struct int_pair {
    int a, b;
} int_pair;

int_pair function(){
    int_pair s;

    s.a = 42;
    s.b = 666;

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Allright so the right way to do this is to make a list and return it yes?

Comment: @Kaspar, the right way depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: A list may be overkill - a struct might do it.

Comment: @fede1024, no need to dynamically allocate in this case. Return by value will suffice.

Comment: If it is a pointer it needs to be dynamically allocated. Yes, a normal struct without a pointer is sufficient. (edit)

Comment: if not mistaken, reference only in c++ and not in pure c?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in python and matlab and possibly other languages but not C, or C++ or other languages.

In C++ you could return a `pair`.

In C you could pass in two pointers and send back the return values that way, or if they belong together make a struct with both values in and return that.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing with that `return` Statement is using the comma expression. What the comma expression does is to evaluate both sub-expressions, from left to right, but return the result of the right sub-expression, meaning the `return` statement returns the result of the right sub-expression as well.

In C you can not return multiple values with the `return` Statement. Only one or none.

Answer (score 3):

you could also use a struct containing two values and then return it.

another solution is also possible if you have two 32 bit values. Infact, you can store both of them in a 64 bit variable. Example:

```
uint32_t a = 10;
uint32_t b = 20;
//store both into c:
uint64_t c = (a << 32) + b;
//restore a and b:
a = c >> 32;
b = c & 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning values from the function to main(). Try to pass them references to the calling function(i.e) their addresses to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an **array** to return the values:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function to generate and return 2 numbers */
int * function( )
{
  static int  r[2];
  int i;

  r[0] = 10;
  r[1] = 20;

  return r;
}

/* main function to call above defined function */
int main ()
{
   /* a pointer to an int */
   int *p;
   int i;

   p = function();
   for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
   {
       printf( "%d\n",*(p + i));
   }

   return 0;
}
```